# How can I translate "creationist"?

Tags: translation

From ReVo I know that *creationism* is ***kreismo*** in Esperanto. 
Is then ***kreismulo*** a person who believes in creationism?

Answer (score 9):

If *kreismo* is creationism (which I would agree with) then, creationist would be *kreism**an**o*, as a creationist is a member of creationism.

Comment: So kreismano, kreismulo, kreismisto kaj kreismemulo are possible translations? I would incline myself to what @johannes-mueller said since kreismo is more of a belief system.

Comment: The ending _-isto_ has two uses: 1) to denote a profession _labori → laboristo_ and 2) to denote a supporter of an _-ism_ _marksismo → marksisto_. Since _kreismo_ is an _-ism_ it is tempting to call a member as _kreisto_. But if you see just the word _kreisto_ and decipher it, you easily land on the first use, a profession, since _kreismo_ isn't that well-known. Then you wonder, professional creator of what? Therefore _kreismano_ is more clearer.

Answer (score 6):

I think *kreismulo* (or even *kreismisto*) is a safer choice, as *kreisto* also means "creator" and I'm not sure I would understand it correctly as referring to a follower of a belief system.

An [item in *Monato*](http://www.esperanto.be/fel/2008/009419.php) uses *kreismemulo*. I would interpret that as "sympathizer with Creationism".

Answer (score 1):

In nearly every case, *-ismo* transforms regularly to -isto*. That is, if the starting point is *kreismo*, then someone who follows this school of thought is a *kreisto*.

It is of course possible to form an expression ending in *ismano*, but I have primarily seen this when the *isto* form is taken for something else - for example, *Esperantismano* is used for members of *Esperantismo*, since *Esperantisto* is defined simply as Esperanto speaker (regardless of the purpose they use the language for.)

I can't say that I have ever heard the word *kreismo* used, but a little bit of poking around the web suggests that it has at least some traction. Any objection to *kreisto* with this sense would apply equally to *kreismo* with this sense.